# python div/paragraph Selenium element not interactable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium. However, when i try to click on a div (or paragraph) (I tried it also with .send(), it changed nothing) it says:
[Error Code]

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x008CFDC3+2555331]
        Ordinal0 [0x008677F1+2127857]
        Ordinal0 [0x00762CD0+1060048]
        Ordinal0 [0x007899F3+1219059]
        Ordinal0 [0x0078913F+1216831]
        Ordinal0 [0x007A7B0C+1342220]
        Ordinal0 [0x00784984+1198468]
        Ordinal0 [0x007A7C14+1342484]
        Ordinal0 [0x007B75FA+1406458]
        Ordinal0 [0x007A7976+1341814]
        Ordinal0 [0x007836B6+1193654]
        Ordinal0 [0x00784546+1197382]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A69622+1619522]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B1882C+2336844]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009623E1+541697]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00961443+537699]
        Ordinal0 [0x0086D18E+2150798]
        Ordinal0 [0x00871518+2168088]
        Ordinal0 [0x00871660+2168416]
        Ordinal0 [0x0087B330+2208560]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76886739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D48AFF+1215]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77D48ACD+1165]
```

My Python Code is the following:

```
size_select_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , "alltricks-ChildSelector-customOptions-group")
    print("selector - found")

    for div in size_select_div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div'):
            print("going theough divs")
            if (div.get_attribute("data-label") == "46"):
                print("Shoe in size 46")
                sleep(2)
                div.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                print("clicked")
            else:
                print("not 46")
```

Does any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

We can not know what exactly happens with your code, however `ElementNotInteractableException` exception can be caused by several causes:

1. Web page rendering still not complete.
   In this case you can add some wait / delay to make the page fully loaded and only then access that element. This should preferably done with Expected Conditions explicit waits. If possible.
2. The element you are trying to access located out of the visible view port.
   In this case you should scroll that element into the view with something like this:

```py
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

where `actions` initialized like this

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

With use of import

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

3. The element you are trying to access is inside some dialog etc. that should be opened etc. in order to access that element